# Align textviews in left and right side of a linear layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I currently doing one of the project from "Google Android Dev". I am facing a problem in my layout design. Kindly help me how to align one textview in left side and right side of a linear layout.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="194dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textAppearanceHeadline6"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/faye" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textAppearanceHeadline6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Faye"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/textAppearanceBody1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textAppearanceHeadline6"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textAppearanceHeadline6">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Age : 7"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start|right"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Hobbies: Sunbathing"
                android:textColor="#5A5656" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Output I am getting]

[image: Result I want!!]

I am new to android so you are most welcome for code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="194dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textAppearanceHeadline6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/faye" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textAppearanceHeadline6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="Faye"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textAppearanceBody1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textAppearanceHeadline6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textAppearanceHeadline6">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:text="Age : 7"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hobbies: Sunbathing"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#5A5656" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Age : 7"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Hobbies: Sunbathing"
            android:textColor="#5A5656" />
```

weight here will allow the first textview to take all the space and will leave the required space for the hobby textview.
Use it as per your requirement.

Comment: I guess there is some mistake in your code it is not working as it need to be. Please check it.